# Possible to remove line between two borders

Tags: html, css

Added Windows 95 clone window to my personal site. In the image you can see there are two divs, one thin div on top (div.title) and a larger div on the bottom (div.body). The div on the bottom has a border on the left, bottom and right (no border on top). The div on top has a border surrounding the entire element. The issue I'm having is the line between where the two borders meet. Is there a way to remove this line to give both borders a seamless look where they meet?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #008284;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("desktop.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins;
  src: url(Poppins-Bold.ttf);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.githubLogo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*windows 95 window css */

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  background: #008284;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.title {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000080;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px #bec2c1 solid;
}

img.title {
  float: left;
}

p.title {
  margin: 2px 0 0 1px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.title button {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 13.5px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ffffff #808080 #808080 #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  text-align: center;
}

div.body {
  padding: 13px 12px 12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 34px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 8px #bec2c1 solid;
  border-left: 8px #bec2c1 solid;
  border-right: 8px #bec2c1 solid;
}

div.body p {
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  font-size: 11px;
}

div.body button {
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  font-size: 11px;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff #808080 #808080 #ffffff;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 20px auto 3px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    <p class="title">Home</p>
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1></h1>
        <h3></h3>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Windows 95 CSS Border Issue]

Comment: _Proper_ [mre] instead of screenshots, please.

Comment: Edited to add minimal reproducible example.

Comment: That doesn't reproduce the issue for me in Chrome or Firefox. At least not at default zoom level. Can you please give details in what browser / under which additional conditions you see this appear?

Comment: I can see the issue in Chrome (v95) on Windows. However it seems like a rendering issue, if I zoom my browser the artefact vanishes.

Comment: Happens to me on 1080p screen on Chrome at default zoom.

Comment: If it's a rendering issue is there any workaround?

Comment: There are some slightly hacky solutions, you could offset the box body to make it overlap slightly under the title, which would probably do the trick.

Comment: It's the background from `.box` "shining through the cracks" between the `title` and `body` elements. It goes away (at least for me) if I remove the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. Element positions may be getting rounded to whole pixels after they have been moved, with rounding happening in different directions, something like that. I wouldn't know an easy solution.

Comment: Seems to be the transform property. Centered the box using flexbox instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #008284;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("desktop.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Poppins;
  src: url(Poppins-Bold.ttf);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.githubLogo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/*windows 95 window css */

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  background: #008284;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 49%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.title {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000080;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px #bec2c1 solid;
}

img.title {
  float: left;
}

p.title {
  margin: 2px 0 0 1px;
  float: left;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.title button {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 13.5px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ffffff #808080 #808080 #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  text-align: center;
}

div.body {
  padding: 13px 12px 12px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 34px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 8px #bec2c1 solid;
  border-left: 8px #bec2c1 solid;
  border-right: 8px #bec2c1 solid;
  margin-top:-1px;
}

div.body p {
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  font-size: 11px;
}

div.body button {
  font-family: "MS Sans Serif";
  font-size: 11px;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff #808080 #808080 #ffffff;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 20px auto 3px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    <p class="title">Home</p>
    <button>X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1></h1>
        <h3></h3>
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was transform property. Removed transform and used flexbox to center div instead resolves the visual border line.

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <div class="containerDiv">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="title">
          <p class="title">Home</p>
          <button>X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
          <div>
            <div><h1>paul phillips</h1><h3>full stack web developer</h3></div>
            <a href="projects.html">projects</a>
            <span> | </span>
            <a href="paul_phillips_cv.pdf" target="_blank">curriculum vitae</a>
            <span> | </span>
            <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
            <div>
              <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"
                ><img class="githubLogo" src="images/GitHub-Mark-Light-64px.png" alt="GitHub Logo"
              /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #008284;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("desktop.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

.containerDiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 6em;
}

h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.githubLogo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/*windows 95 window css */
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.box {
  width: 700px;
  background: #008284;
}

div.title {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000080;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px #bec2c1 solid;
}

img.title {
  float: left;
}

p.title {
  margin: -4px 0 0 4px;
  float: left;
  font-family: "Win95Bold";
  font-size: 0.8em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.title button {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  float: right;
  width: 20px;
  height: 13.5px;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ffffff #808080 #808080 #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Win95";
  text-align: center;
}

div.body {
  padding: 13px 12px 12px;
  width: calc(100% - 32px);
  border-bottom: 7px #bec2c1 solid;
  border-left: 7px #bec2c1 solid;
  border-right: 7px #bec2c1 solid;
}

div.body p {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-size: 11px;
}

div.body button {
  font-family: "Win95";
  font-size: 11px;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ffffff #808080 #808080 #ffffff;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  margin: 20px auto 3px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some corrected code from OP's question so that your answer  is easy to interpret?